# How to make the transition to the next page in imacros?

Tags: javascript, java, imacros

Here is my code :

```
add !var1 {{!loop}}
tag pos=1 type=a attr=txt:{{!var}}
```

I thought that this code will help, but no. It just flips through it and does not go to the next google page.

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
SET !LOOP 2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:{{!LOOP}}
'WAIT SECONDS=3
```